# Grinding on Normal-Classic mode FE:3H

Tags: fire-emblem-three-houses

I’ve read on various posts on gamefaqs that you can’t grind on Hard/Classic because maps are tied to some “activity points” while on Normal there should be a map you can repeat again and again

I’ve been playing on Normal/Classic though, but I don’t see this map. All maps cost 1.

I am on the beginning  of august, just received the sword of the creator.

How can I grind in this mode? I’m not even actually looking to maximize my character level, I just want to get all Class Masteries.

Edit: I don’t see the infinite map mentioned in the linked possible answer...

Comment: With regards to your edit, you can go ahead and post a new answer on the linked question if you have new information.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I posted a comment on the accepted answer instead. Will that suffice?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Yes, a comment is just fine.